# Network graph In Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-animation, matplotlib-widget

I had a question about python matplotlib I wanted to know in this library Is it possible to make grid diagrams in which circles are drawn and connected and intersected by lines? In the network graphs that I saw, the circles are divided like cells, and if they are close to other circles, they are connected by a line. And if they move away, the line is disconnected

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEom4.jpg)I expected to make a few circles, 4 at most They appear randomly and are connected by a line, and when they move away, the line disappears and they disappear.The picture I posted may convey what I mean And you understand I saw a lot of network graphs that circles and lines are distorted and shake and I wanted to make one. How to make something like this in matplotlib? And is it possible to make a two-dimensional or three-dimensional network graph in matplotlib, where the circles are extracted and connected with a line? And after the circles move away, do the lines and circles disappear and new circles appear randomly?